# Copy xml with xslt skipping top level nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

How to copy xml document skipping some top level nodes. For example:

Input:

```
<root>
 <subroot>
   <nodeX id="1">
     <!-- inner structure -->
   </nodeX>
   <nodeX id="2">
     <!-- inner structure -->
   </nodeX>
   <!-- other nodes -->
  </subroot>
<root>
```

Output:

```
   <nodeX id="1">
     <!-- inner structure -->
   </nodeX>
   <nodeX id="2">
     <!-- inner structure -->
   </nodeX>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root | subroot">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

should. If you want or need something more generic then make the second template

```
<xsl:template match="/* | /*/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is it possible to skip another nodes that are sub-nodes of root? These nodes match /root/subrootX|/root/subrootY but I dont want to copy them.

Comment: Simply add any pattern you don't want to copy to the second template match pattern e.g. `<xsl:template match="/root | /root/subroot | /root/subrootX | /root/subrootY"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`. Or if you know you don't want to copy any child of any root element use the generic `match="/* | /*/*"` I already posted.